# Passing values between two structs thats have a slice inside

Tags: go

i have 2 structs with a slice inside like this:

```
type BookX struct {
  SomeValue string
  Book1 []Book1
}
type Book1 struct {
  Name string
  Author string
}

type BookY struct {
  SomeValue string
  Book2 []Book2
}
type Book2 struct {
  Name string
  Author string
}
```

And i want to pass the values inside the first slice in the struct BookX to the other slice inside the BookY.

Tried this way but doesn't work:

```
func someName(bookX BookX){
  var bookY BookY
  bookY.Book2 = append(bookY.Book2, bookX.Book1...)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Book1` and `Book2` are the diffrent type even they have same members. You can not append `[]Book1` to `[]Book2`.

One solution is to create a `Book2` instance from `Book1` and add them to `[]Book2`.

```
func someName(bookX BookX){
  var bookY BookY
  for _, book1 := range bookx.Book1 {
    book2 := Book2 {
      Name: book1.Name,
      Author: book1.Author,
    }
    bookY.Book2 = append(bookY.Book2, book2)
  }
}
```